# Dynamics crm - use default CSS for custom HTML webresource

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamics-crm

There is lot's of tutorials on how to use custom webresources in dynamics CRM, I know.

I have made custom form with HTML/jQuery and now I need to style it, so it looks like a part of CRM.

Is there any way I can "rob" CRM and use its original CSSs, or do I have to go from element to element and manually copy style properties, to get the same look? Or is this resource available somewhere on the internet?

Comment: You could reference system CSSs but in practice you'll only need a few styles to get your custom html look like CRM forms, so the actual effort to extract the needed styles or identify the exact styles you need to reference is basically the same imho.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling web resources in Dynamics CRM 2016 supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240270/styling-web-resources-in-dynamics-crm-2016-supported)